# Flight Plans filed with the FAA

Tags: data-request, usa, transportation

Various apps such as [Window Seat](http://www.windowseatapp.com/) can access the flight plans that aircraft -- specifically airline flights -- have filed with the FAA.  This is NOT about delays, nor about flight *tracking*, but things like the proposed departure time, the filed route of flight (shown on the Window Seat front page, starting with "SFO8 SFO SAC J32 BAM..."), and the filed altitude.

While the FAA has various APIs and sources of data, I haven't been able to locate a way to access ***this*** information.  I realize that various flight tracking services such as [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/) offer this and a great deal of other data by subscription, but it would be nice if I could get it from the source rather than paying a third party for it, and since apps like WindowSeat seem to get access, it looks like it should be available ***somewhere***.